# Steam store not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wine, steam, playonlinux

I have installed Steam on Ubuntu.

I have already used PlayOnLinux and Wine to get Steam up, but **nothing ever shows up in the store**. I installed Steam using the instructions on [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YKYzrU8qc7w):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
sudo apt-get install playonlinux
```

Run `playonlinux` and select "Install a program", search for Steam and install it, clicking yes to everything in the dialog.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to AskUbuntu!

I've had this problem before, it seems to be actually a known issue with web-based UI elements:
https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=19444

You can try starting steam with `-no-cef-sandbox` argument. (Although it may be a security risk. I would use it as a temporary solution). 
[image]

---

Comment: Thank you, i made the change as you said,  but it isnt working. could it do with not having wine 1.9.23, i only have 1.7.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Maybe it will work with a newer version of wine? Try installing the latest and see if it works.

Answer (score 4):

For those adding the -no-cef-sandbox option, and it still not working, I found that when installing Steam via winetricks, the .desktop file that's placed on the desktop actually links to a shortcut on the wine prefixes desktop folder. Adding the -no-cef-sandbox option will not work here as it needs to be passed directly to .exe.

If you open the desktop file in an editor

```
gedit Steam.desktop
```

and point directly to Steam.exe by editing the Exec attribute. In my case:

```
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/nick/.wine" wine "/home/nick/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/Steam/steam.exe" -no-cef-sandbox
```

*Don't forget to change the user, and ensure the path is correct for your install

This allowed the store page to load in my case.

Answer (score 3):

If you have winetricks, install the following packages within winetricks:

```
steam
d3dx9_42
vcrun2008
xact
vcrun2015
```

Then run Steam with the -no-cef-sandbox option. This should allow Steam to display webpages.

If it still doesn't work, make sure wine is upgraded to the latest release of wine-staging (which you'll want to set up with CSMT anyway for the performance increase in games.)

Comment: `WINEPREFIX=... winetricks vcrun2008 vcrun2015` is what fixed it for me. Thought I'd already installed them but clearly not. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This also works if you run steam.exe with wine directly from the command line, so something like `wine /home/$user/.wine/drive_c/Program Files\ (x86)/Steam/Steam.exe -no-cef-sandbox`. You just, as indicated earlier, need to make sure you are running the option against the steam.exe binary directly. You could also make a shortcut with the same pathing and option if you like. I usually make scripts that do these things and then alias them in .bashrc file. Who really wants to type that all the time...

Comment: This worked for me when I used `wine-staging` but not `wine-stable`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had had the same problem. And I tried fixing the problem by adding the -no-cef-sandbox. However, the problem still happen.

I reinstall steam and run it again then PlayOnLinux asked to install Mono.
After installing Mono, the problem was fixed. I don't know why!!

wine-version : 2.0 staging

Answer (score 0):

With patience I tried all these things one at a time, no joy.  Then instead of installing with winetricks I went into POL ... and the first thing worked!

POL / Configure / Install Components / Microsoft Core Fonts and the store LIT UP!

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and what solved it for me on POL was after installing Steam, go to Configure and install Components and install DirectX9. After installing this the store loaded with no problems at all.